# LOGGER in my Coprocessor doesn't work

Tags: hbase

I'm writing observer coprocessor which replicates a specific table to child.

My JAVA file likes below.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.BaseRegionObserver;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.ObserverContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.WALEdit;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class trigger_test extends BaseRegionObserver {

    private byte[] master;
    private byte[] family;
    public static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(HRegion.class);

    @Override
    public void start(CoprocessorEnvironment e) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = e.getConfiguration();
        master = Bytes.toBytes(conf.get("master"));
        family = Bytes.toBytes(conf.get("family"));
    }

    private void insert(RegionCoprocessorEnvironment env, byte[] row, Put put) throws IOException {
        //HTable masterTable = env.getTable(TableName.valueOf(master));
        HTableInterface masterTable = env.getTable(TableName.valueOf(master));
        try {
            masterTable.put(put);

        } finally {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");

            masterTable.close();

        }
    }

    private void remove(RegionCoprocessorEnvironment env, byte[] row) throws IOException {
        //HTable masterTable = env.getTable(TableName.valueOf(master));
        HTableInterface masterTable = env.getTable(TableName.valueOf(master));
        try {
            Delete delete = new Delete(row);

            //delete.deleteFamily(family);

            masterTable.delete(delete);

        } finally {
            masterTable.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void postPut(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> e, Put put, WALEdit edit, Durability durability) throws IOException {
        RegionCoprocessorEnvironment env = e.getEnvironment();

        byte[] row = put.getRow();
            LOG.debug("THIS IS DEBUG LOG");

        insert(env, row, put);
    }

    @Override
    public void postDelete(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> e, Delete delete, WALEdit edit, Durability durability) throws IOException {
        RegionCoprocessorEnvironment env = e.getEnvironment();

        byte[] row = delete.getRow();

        remove(env, row);

    }       
}
```

My `~/conf/log4j.properites` likes below.

```
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hbase.root.logger=DEBUG,console
hbase.security.logger=INFO,console
hbase.log.dir=.
hbase.log.file=hbase.log

# Define the root logger to the system property "hbase.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hbase.root.logger}

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=ALL

#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hbase.log.dir}/${hbase.log.file}

# Rollver at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# 30-day backup
#log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2}: %m%n

# Rolling File Appender properties
hbase.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hbase.log.maxbackupindex=20

# Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hbase.log.dir}/${hbase.log.file}

log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=${hbase.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=${hbase.log.maxbackupindex}

log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2}: %m%n

#
# Security audit appender
#
hbase.security.log.file=SecurityAuth.audit
hbase.security.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hbase.security.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.RFAS=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAS.File=${hbase.log.dir}/${hbase.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxFileSize=${hbase.security.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxBackupIndex=${hbase.security.log.maxbackupindex}
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.category.SecurityLogger=${hbase.security.logger}
log4j.additivity.SecurityLogger=false
#log4j.logger.SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController=TRACE
#log4j.logger.SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.visibility.VisibilityController=TRACE

#
# Null Appender
#
log4j.appender.NullAppender=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender

#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this 
#
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2}: %m%n

# Custom Logging levels

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSNamesystem=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase=DEBUG
# Make these two classes INFO-level. Make them DEBUG to see more zk debug.
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher=INFO
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.dfs=DEBUG
# Set this class to log INFO only otherwise its OTT
# Enable this to get detailed connection error/retry logging.
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation=TRACE


# Uncomment this line to enable tracing on _every_ RPC call (this can be a lot of output)
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseServer.trace=DEBUG

# Uncomment the below if you want to remove logging of client region caching'
# and scan of .META. messages
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation=INFO
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner=INFO
```

I checked hbase log files on all nodes but there is no debug string.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to change `LogFactory.getLog(HRegion.class);` to `LogFactory.getLog(trigger_test.class);`. Just give it a try. This is what I was able to figure out at the first glance.

Comment: Also, not sure if you there is a typo (from your side while typing question) in the filename of `~/conf/log4j.properites`. The `properties` is misspelled. May be this is the reason why HBase is not able to fetch the Logger configuration.